# Join t1 on a, b, and c but only join on c if c is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want some t-sql syntactically correct version of what is below (hopefully what is bellow is human readable)

```
select* from table1
join table2 
on table1.a = table2.a
and table1.b = table2.b
and table1.c = 
when table1.c IS NOT NULL THEN table2.c
when table1.c IS NULL THEN --dont join on column c, just use the other joins
END

I tried the syntax below but it doesn't seem to work (any explanation of why this is incorrect is also appreciated)

select* from table1
join table2 
on table1.a = table2.a
and table1.b = table2.b
and table1.c = 
when table1.c IS NOT NULL THEN table2.c
when table1.c IS NULL THEN null --this line is just guessing, but it doesnt work
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    T1.my_column,
    T2.my_other_column
FROM
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON
    T2.a = T1.a AND
    T2.b = T1.b AND
    (T2.c = T1.c OR T1.c IS NULL)
```

Alternatively, if T2.c can never be `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    T1.my_column,
    T2.my_other_column
FROM
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON
    T2.a = T1.a AND
    T2.b = T1.b AND
    T2.c = COALESCE(T1.c, T2.c)
```

I like the first in any case, due to readability.

EDIT:
`COALESCE` returns the first non-null parameter pass into the function. So, if `T1.c` were `NULL` above, it would return `T2.c`. If `T2.c` is also `NULL` then it's going to try to evaluate `NULL = NULL`, which is going to be **false**.

You can get around this by doing `COALESCE(T2.c, -1) = COALESCE(T1.c, T2.c, -1)`, but then SQL isn't going to be able to use indexes very well.

If you want to `JOIN` on them both being `NULL` then you can use the bit above, or just spell out each possible combination:

```
(
    (T2.c IS NULL AND T1.c IS NULL) OR
    T2.c = T1.c
)
```

Comment: this works perfectly although im not sure what coalesce is doing (i assume checking for null if no match?). as a followup, how would i join t2.c on t1.c where they are both null?  I understand I cant join on null, but this would be very useful for an unusual data migration I am working on

Comment: I've added some explanation to the answer rather than trying to put it all into comments.

Answer (score 1):

a trick that typically gives better performance

```
SELECT
    T1.my_column,
    T2.my_other_column
FROM
    Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 
  ON T2.a = T1.a 
 AND T2.b = T1.b 
 AND T2.c = isnull(T1.c, T2.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
select* from table1
join table2 
on table1.a = table2.a
and table1.b = table2.b
and (table1.c is not null or table1.c = table2.c)
```